# Virtual Old Printer

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, printer

I have a recipe printer. It is working fine on Windows 8.1, but on windows 10 it is not working well. I tried to connect with its support team and they told me the firmware is old and can not be updated.

some told me to install older windows on a VM and try to install the printer on it. But really my printer is working with the software. connecting the software to VM also is possible for me with some programming tricks. but installing VM just for a printer is expensive.

Is there any lightweight software (virtualization software) that can run the printer in compatibility mode or something like this?

Comment: How isn't it working well? Is it a driver or software issue? And for that matter what is a recipe printer?

Comment: a recipe printer is what you see in small shopping centers. it prints garbage data or sometimes it gives errors on printing. sometimes it does not print anything and the documents will be in the queue forever.

Comment: That sounds a lot like... most printers tbh

Comment: yeah but it is working on older windows than windows 10

Comment: You could try a free VM. Search "windows 8 vm free"